# how to change the microphone source dynamically gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I have a client in gstreamer which is sending his audio to another client. I want the sender client to be able to change between different audio sources (Microphones in the device) dynamically.

I am using wasapisrc for getting the audio stream from the microphone
I tried changing the device property of the wasapisrc (when the connection is established) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use input-selector element to switch between input sources

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/input-selector.html